# Performance improvement of for loop and synset matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, nlp, wordnet

I am working on the project to find similar sentence from the list of 1000 sentences. I am using `wordnet` `Synset` matching for that purpose, but the problem is that it is taking too much time to process the result. Can I increase the performance of that by any way?

Here is the function that is taking so much time:

```
def find_similarity(self, synsets1, synsets2):
    # For each word in the first sentence
    if synsets1 == [] or synsets2 == []:
        return 0.0
    score, count = 0.0, 0
    for synset in synsets1:
        vals = []
        # best_score = max([synset.path_similarity(ss) for ss in synsets2])
        for ss in synsets2:
            if ss and synset:
                sim = synset.path_similarity(ss)
                if sim:
                    vals.append(sim)
                else:
                    vals.append(0)
        score = vals
    return score
```

Here I am calling it via:

```
for sent in sentence_list:
    result.append(self.find_similarity(sent, input))
```

Currently it is taking around 20-25 seconds, can I speed it up by any means?

Comment: A few things: First, this is a triply nested `for` loop which has a time complexity of `O(n^3)`. That will almost always be slow, especially with large inputs. Second, if your indentation is correct here, only the last iteration of `for synset in synsets1:` survives. So any loops before that can be omitted if your logic is correct.

Comment: Hi @Axe319 I just pasted some of the code, to have an idea what I want and just realise the mistakes and updated the correct code now.

Comment: What prevents you from piping this into a Thread pool with `multiprocessing`? To me, this seems trivially parallelizable (i.e., you can execute all the calls of `find_similarity` in parallel). This gives you probably the easiest speedup, unless you want to use some form of (LRU) caching or general index structures..

Comment: @dennlinger Will caching/indexes help? Isn't comparing all elements in a synset to all other elements in a synset O(N^2)?  (I agree making this parallel is the easy way to reduce wall clock time, at least.)

Comment: @dennlinger will by doing it using multiprocessing, does it hamper the index in result, where I am appending the value in the result variable?

Comment: @dennlinger Also can you please tell me a way to do it through multiprocessing, I read out that but did not succeed to do it.